# How to mock only a specific http resource (URL) in Angular

Tags: javascript, http, rest, angularjs, mocking

I'm working in a team split into front-end and back-end developers. Sometimes, the front-end wants to make some REST requests to a http address / REST-resource that *isn't yet implemented*.

In `ngMockE2E` there's a [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend) service that seems quite useful for this. The question is, how do I mock only **some** specific urls/rest resources?

I want most requests like e.g. `GET /users.json` to go through to the backend server as usual. *But while waiting* for e.g. `GET /users/tommy/profile.json` to get implemented (by the back-end guys), it would be nice to have some "pretend response", aka mocking, so we can keep working. How should one go about?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try include this in your project:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
}).run(function($httpBackend) {
    // make sure we have access to
    $httpBackend.whenGET('*').passThrough();

    // here use your mocking data using $httpBackend
});
```